# $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ whose partials exist. Show: $\partial _xf \:\:\mathrm{continuous} \Rightarrow f \:\:\mathrm {differentiable}$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be a function whose partial derivatives exist.
Now i have to show: $$\partial _xf \:\:\mathrm{continuous} \Rightarrow f  \:\:\mathrm {differentiable}$$

Any tipps on how to approach this? (I really don't even have an intuitive view of why this should work) Thanks in advance!

Comment: The theorem I know requires continuity of $\partial_yf$ as well, but it also has a stronger thesis ($f$ being $C^1$, obviously). Are you sure the statement is this one? (or perhaps I misundrstood the notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Write
$$
f(x + h_1, y + h_2) - f(x, y) = f(x + h_1, y + h_2) - f(x, y + h_2) + f(x, y + h_2) - f(x, y) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi, y + h_2) h_1 + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) h_2 + o(h),
$$
where $\xi \in (x, x + h_1)$. What happens as $h \rightarrow 0$? Note that we have not assumed that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous so $f$ might not be $C^1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical theorem in analysis, assuming both (all) partial derivatives are continuous

By definition, $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $J$ such that
$$\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}} \frac{\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}+\mathbf{h}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}) - \mathbf{J}\mathbf{(h)}\|_{\mathbf{R}^{n}}}{\| \mathbf{h} \|_{\mathbf{R}^{m}}}=0.$$

Recall that the natural differential $J$ for $f$ is given by the Jacobi matrix, whose entries are the partial derivatives of $f$.

Now write out the numerator in the definition of differentiable at $x_0$ so that it reads like $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x^i-x_0^i)$ using the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem .

Then you can bound the above term using continuity of the partial derivatives.

The solution can be found at page 201 of the following skript (in German, but yeah, math is math) https://people.math.ethz.ch/~struwe/Skripten/Analysis-I-II-final-6-9-2012.pdf

Comment: Does the hypothesis of the question say that $\partial_yf$ is continuous? I don't see it.

Comment: Not really. I actually thought that $x$ referred to any variable, so if it is *not* the case, my hint does not work.

Comment: I thought that equation was the *definition* of differentiability. I guess different sources have different conventions. What's the definition according to your source?

Comment: the equation *is* the definition of differentiability. Was it not clear? I have edited the text. By the way, the definition I use is the one given on the Skript I cited (p.199) and Wiki.

Comment: the assumption that BOTH partials are continuous is wrong, only one is continuous, but both exist